# in_widget_form detect sidebar id

Tags: widgets

I have extensively looked for this and can't find a php answer, only js or css.

In my widget class `dynamic_sidebar_params` I have this to only output css classes on that instance:

```
if ( 'sidebar' === $params[0][ 'id' ] || 'after-entry' === $params[0][ 'id' ] ) :

   // Add the classes added in the Widget Style Field
    if ( ! empty( $instance[ 'prefix_select_class' ] ) ) :

         $class = $instance[ 'prefix_select_class' ];

         $params[0]['before_widget'] = preg_replace('/class="/', 'class="'. $class . ' ',  $params[0]['before_widget'], 1 );

     endif; // cherish_select_class not empty

endif; //specific widgets
```

But on the `in_widget_form` I can't get the $params, no clue how, is there a way to not show certain fields based on the sidebar id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between *sidebars* and *widgets* is stored in the `sidebars_widgets` option, as a serialized array that might look like this (expanded):

```
Array
(
    [orphaned_widgets_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => recent-posts-2
        )

    [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array
        (
            [0] => calendar-2
        )

    [sidebar-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => recent-posts-5
            [1] => text-6
            [2] => text-2
            [3] => search-6
            [4] => text-3
        )

    [sidebar-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => text-4
        )

    [sidebar-3] => Array
        (
            [0] => text-5
            [1] => recent-posts-6
            [2] => search-7
        )

)
```

WordPress uses the [`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sidebars_widgets/) function to fetch this  relationship.

If we want to find in which sidebar e.g. the fifth instance of the *Recent Posts* widget ( `recent-posts-5` ) belongs to, then we can search the array and find that it's the `sidebar-1` sidebar.

**Helper function:**

We could do that with a helper function like this one:

```
/**
 * @param string       $widget_id  Widget ID e.g. 'recent-posts-5'
 * @return string|null $sidebar_id Sidebar ID e.g. 'sidebar-1'
 */
function wpse_get_sidebar_id_from_widget_id( $widget_id )
{
    $sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    foreach( (array) $sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar )
    {
        if( in_array( $widget_id, (array) $sidebar, true ) )
            return $sidebar_id;
    }
    return null; // not found case
}
```

In [PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) we could use `?string` as a *nullable* string type.

**Usage example:**

```
$sidebar_id = wpse_get_sidebar_id_from_widget_id( 'recent-post-5' );
```

So within your `in_widget_form` callback you could try (untested):

```
add_action( 'in_widget_form', function( $widget_object, $return, $instance )
{
    $sidebar_id = wpse_get_sidebar_id_from_widget_id( $widget_object->id );

    if( is_string( $sidebar_id ) )
    {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

**Update:**

This seems to have been solved similarly here: [How to determine which sidebar the widget has been added to, via widget admin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/how-to-determine-which-sidebar-the-widget-has-been-added-to-via-widget-admin).

Comment: That was very helpful!